# Using California SRS Epoch 2017.5 (NAD83) in ArcGIS Desktop

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system, united-states

I'm using RTK with SOPAC stations (http://sopac-csrc.ucsd.edu). The relevant reference system is California SRS Epoch 2017.5 (NAD83).

I am trying to load the coordinates I got in this system, but I couldn't find any transformation from this system to any other standard system (for example: WGS84, NAD83, NAD_1983_StatePlane_California_II_FIPS_0402).
I even asked Esri but they said they couldn't help me and that such transformations doesn't exist in ArcGIS Pro.

What should I do?

Comment: What was Esri’s exact response?

Comment: What coordinate system are you trying to transform into?

Comment: @PolyGeo, that there are no relevant transformations.

Comment: @Mintx, to NAD_1983_StatePlane_California_II_FIPS_0402 for example. Or to WGS84 / NAD83

Comment: Are you using ArcGIS Pro or ArcMap?

Comment: @PolyGeo, ArcGIS Pro

Comment: Please use the [edit] button beneath your question to revise it with any requested clarifications.

Answer (score 1):

Note: I work for Esri.

We have no transformations for California SRS Epoch 2017.5 (NAD83). I think it's  actually a time-fixed version of NAD83 (2011), or at least closely related. I've never been able to find a transformation for it.

You could use the Create Custom Geographic Transformation tool to define a null or zero parameter transformation to NAD 1983 (2011). Converting to WGS 84 or NAD83 (original) should probably use a non-zero transformation because the current WGS 84 realization is generally about 1 m offset from NAD 1983 (2011).

Comment: It is documented that CSRS system is consistent with NAD 83(2011) epoch 2010.00. What "consistent* means in this context? Also, what's NAD 83(2011) epoch 2010.00 EPSG/ESRI code is? Is it 6318?